# How do I scale an SVG based on my website's window size

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a settings icon svg file which will scale depending on then window width. I've tried to do this by creating a function in JavaScript that changes the element's width and height based on the window size but this doesn't work. (Btw i'm testing it with a width of 360 pixels but the svg's size is about 300 pixels).

The HTML:

```
<img id="settings-icon" class="icon" src="images/icons/settings-icon.svg" onclick="settingsPage();" alt="Settings" />
```

The JavaScript:

```
var settings_icon = scaleIcon(dcument.getElementById("settings-icon"));
scaleIcon(settings_icon);

function scaleIcon(icon) {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if (w <= 360) {
        icon.width = "44";
        icon.height="44";
    }
    else if (w <= 400) {
        icon.width = "48";
        icon.height="48";
    }
    else if (w <= 440) {
        icon.width = "52";
        icon.height="52";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you spelt 'document' as 'dcument'. Also, try using `icon.style.width` and `icon.style.height`. Also, remember to add the units for your measurements. Example: `icon.style.width = "44vw";`

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. (i had document spelt right on the actual thing)

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. Nothing has changed, the SVG is still taking up most of the screen

Comment: Can you attach an example? Maybe a JSFiddle or Codepen so that I can help you.

Comment: In the end I've decided to just use the html attribute width to 7% to stay the same. The work involved in trying to figure this out is too much for the pay off of something that may look slightly better. I'm going to set this answer as correct because I've seen other examples where this has worked and people have confirmed it